# Mandelbrot set not displaying properly

Tags: opengl, mathematics, rendering, shaders, glsl

I am trying to render mandelbrot set using glsl. I'm not sure why its not rendering the correct shape. Does the mandelbrot calculation require values to be within a  range for the (x,y) [ or (real, imag) ] ? 
Here is a screenshot:

[image]

---

I render a quad as follows:

```
float w2 = 6;
float h2 = 5;
glBegin(GL_QUADS);

glVertex3f(-w2, h2, 0.0);
glVertex3f(-w2, -h2, 0.0);

glVertex3f(w2, -h2, 0.0);
glVertex3f(w2, h2, 0.0);

glEnd();
```

My vertex shader:

```
varying vec3 Position;

void main(void)
{
    Position = gl_Vertex.xyz;

    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
}
```

My fragment shader (where all the meat is):

```
uniform float MAXITERATIONS;

varying vec3 Position;

void main (void)  
{     
   float zoom = 1.0;
   float centerX = 0.0;
   float centerY = 0.0;

   float real = Position.x * zoom + centerX;
   float imag = Position.y * zoom + centerY;

   float r2 = 0.0;
   float iter;

   for(iter = 0.0; iter < MAXITERATIONS && r2 < 4.0; ++iter)
   {
    float tempreal = real;

    real = (tempreal * tempreal) + (imag * imag);
    imag = 2.0 * real * imag;

    r2 = (real * real) + (imag * imag);
   }

   vec3 color;

   if(r2 < 4.0)
    color = vec3(1.0);
   else
    color = vec3( iter / MAXITERATIONS );

gl_FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was my fragment shader. Here is the correct version:

```
uniform float MAXITERATIONS;

varying vec3 Position;

void main (void)  
{     
   float zoom = 1.0;
   float centerX = 0.0;
   float centerY = 0.0;

   float real = Position.x * zoom + centerX;
   float imag = Position.y * zoom + centerY;
   float Creal = real;
   float Cimag = imag;

   float r2 = 0.0;
   float iter;

   for(iter = 0.0; iter < MAXITERATIONS && r2 < 4.0; ++iter)
   {
    float tempreal = real;

    real = (tempreal * tempreal) - (imag * imag) + Creal;
    imag = (2.0 * tempreal * imag) + Cimag;

    r2 = (real * real) + (imag * imag);
   }

   vec3 color;

   if(r2 < 4.0)
    color = vec3(1.0);
    else
    color = vec3( iter / MAXITERATIONS );

    gl_FragColor = vec4(color, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: The best answers sometimes are the ones you come up with on your own, preceded by slapping your forehead with your hand :)

Comment: @espais: ha ha. I couldn't agree more.